# PHP / C++: shm_open() error when sharing memory

Tags: php, c++, linux, shared-memory, lighttpd

I've been all over the internet looking for an answer to my problem. Here is the setup, I am running embedded Linux (created with Yocto) which is running the Lighttpd web server with PHP5. In my C++ code I have the following:

```
shared = shm_open(SHARED_FILE_NAME, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
ftruncate(shared, FILE_SIZE);
map = mmap(...);
// shm_unlink() isn't called until my C++ thread ends.
```

Everything works well and I do not get any errors and other C++ processes and threads are also able to access the shared memory and map without any problems (I have one writer thread and all other threads and processes do a read only on the memory). The memory is used as a ring buffer where the writing thread is updating data very quickly. The problems start to occur when trying to access that same memory in PHP. In PHP I do (need read only):

```
<?php
$shm_key = ftok("/dev/shm/shared_file.shm", 'c');
$shm_id = shm_open($shm_key, "a", 0, 0);
...
?>
```

When looking at the value from `ftok()` it returns a non `-1` number which means it did not fail. I do get a fail on the PHP's `shm_open()` call which reads:

```
Warning: shmop_open(): unable to attach or create shared memory segment in /www/pages/shared.php on line 9
```

I've changed the permission of the file with `chmod 777 /dev/shm/shared.shm` just to rule out any file permission issues. Also when I run `ipcs -m` I do not get any listings for shared memory segments, yet my C++ code is running just fine. I've also looked for SELinux and tried entering `setenforce 0` but I get a response of `-sh: setenforce: command not found` so I figure this isn't an issue. I've also tried running `wget <local ip address>/shared.php` to see if running locally would return the correct data but when looking at the file which was returned it had the same error messages.

I am looking to be able to have a web page on my embedded system read this shared memory and stream back chunks of binary to feed a graph when a request comes in (not interested in web sockets at the time). I am able to get named pipes to work across PHP and C++ just fine but I need shared memory for this application and the shared memory access seems to be troublesome. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: strace the PHP and see what the errno result is to the underlying shm_open() library call.  As an aside: please remove the 'lighttpd' tag from this question.  Test your code as the same user who created the shared memory segment to see if it is a permissions error for the different user potentially running your PHP via lighttpd.  If so, try using fchmod() in your C++ to set the permissions on the shared memory segment after you create it.  (BTW, starting your variables with '_' is forbidden by C++ standard.  You're not the compiler, standard library, or kernel)

Comment: When looking at the documentation for `fchmod()` it does the same as when I entered `chmod 777 ...` from above. I am also able to use PHP's `fopen()`, `fread()` and `fclose()` without any access errors and it finds the shared memory file just fine. I do not know how to trace down further in PHP beyond the `Warning: ...` I posted above. I also tried running Lighttpd as root but that requires a recompile on Lighttpd's code (unable to get to at the moment).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftok.php and check the (integer) return value of ftok().  Does it match the shared memory segment you created in C++?  Tr using "" instead of 'c' in your ftok() in PHP.

Comment: +gstrauss: In my post I stated that `ftok()` does not return `-1` meaning it did not fail. I also mentioned that when using the command `ipcs -m` I do not get any segments listed but I am able to access the shared memory from C/C++ code just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing PHP functions that need to use C Shared Memory. As your code, my C functions use shm_open, mmap, etc.. and I guess to use PHP ftok(), shmop_open() to access the C's shared memory but this PHP functions don't work.
The two area are not compatible. I found different properties of the two areas in this documents http://menehune.opt.wfu.edu/Kokua/More_SGI/007-2478-008/sgi_html/ch03.html:

- C (with shm_open, mmap, like the Straton source code) use “POSIX Shared Memory”
- PHP (with shmop_* functions) use “System V Shared Memory”

I suggest you to try with Sync http://php.net/manual/en/book.sync.php: you need the PECL sync extension.